# Configure UICollectionViewCells having same cell type but different UI styles

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView` that has the same cell type, but every cell has different UI properties like `background color`, `textColor` ...

I could configure them inside `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell` as below:

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let item = indexPath.item
    switch item {
    case 1:
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(forIndexPath: indexPath) as ACollectionViewCell
        cell.ScoreName.text = xxx
        cell.ScoreName.textColor = xxx
        cell.score.text = xxx
        cell.score.backgroundColor = xxx
        cell.....

        return cell
    case 2: ...
    case 3: ...
    case 4: ...
    case 5: ...
    case 6:
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(forIndexPath: indexPath) as BCollectionViewCell
        cell.title.text = "xxx xxx"
        cell.score.isHidden = true
        return cell
    default:

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(forIndexPath: indexPath) as DCollectionViewCell
        cell.title.text = "xxx"
        cell.score.text = "xx"
        cell.score.backgroundColor = .green
        cell....
        return cell
    }
}
```

As you can see from case 1 to 5 same cell type with different UI properties, it is not appealing at all also it is not scalable so what is the best approach to deal with such configuration ?

Answer (score 1):

You need keep data in memory so you have to store the configuration of cell due to reusable nature of `UICollectionViewCell`.

```
let dictForCell = ["color":UIColor.redColor(),"isHidden":false] //add key value according to your need
let arrOfCell   = [dictForCell] //also add dictionary of detail

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let dictData = [indexPath.row]
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(forIndexPath: indexPath) as ACollectionViewCell  
        cell.ScoreName.textColor = dictData["color"] as! UIColor
        cell.score.isHidden = dictData["color"] as! Bool        
        cell.score.text = xxx
        cell.score.backgroundColor = xxx
        cell.ScoreName.text = xxx
        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

background color, textColor, etc. should be added as variables in the object you use to populate that collection view. Each object will have its own variables which will be used to customize the cell.

Comment: So I have to extract the data from my model and put it with the UI properties in a new object ?

Comment: Or change your model to include these UI attributes